# Can Firefox detect MetaKey?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm working on a Firefox extension and struggle with the meta key (<kbd>Windows</kbd> key on my keyboard). `KeyboardEvent.metaKey` is supposed to detect it but always returns false. (You can try it out [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey) or even easier [in the jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.metakey/).)

I can reproduce this with Firefox 48.0 on KDE 16.08 / Gentoo and Firefox 47.0.1 on Windows 10. I also tried all combinations of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> but nothing registered as meta.

Chrome 53.0 does not have that problem, btw.

Comment: It appears to be ignored in Microsoft Edge, too. However, even if you can get it to work in a cross-browser fashion, I'm not sure relying on it would make for a good user experience, at least in Windows. No matter what, the OS is going to capture the key press and the Start menu is going to appear every time the combination happens.

Comment: Good point about Windows, hadn't thought of that. My alternative for FF is Alt but it doesn't work in Chrome (I'm not even getting the event for that particular key combo). So... Chrome on Windows is still unsolved.

Comment: You can capture `Event.altKey` in a `keydown` or `keyup` event handler in Chrome.

Comment: I worded that badly. For reasons unknown to me many, many key events do not even show up in the extension I write - I guess the page I am extending or the browser swallows them. In Chrome, the one I want (Alt+Shift+N) is one of them, so I did not even get to the point where I have to fiddle with `keydown`, `keyup`. Although now that I think about it, it might be worth checking out whether those phases see more events...

Comment: Please specify the type of Firefox add-on which you are working on: [tag:firefox-webextensions] ([WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions)), [tag:fiirefox-addon-sdk] ([Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK)), [tag:firefox-addon-restartless] ([Bootstraped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions)), or [tag:xul] ([Overlay/XUL/Legacy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions))? Please [edit] the appropriate tag for that into the question.

Answer (score 2):

**No, and Yes:**
Yes, Firefox can detect the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, but not as the "Meta" key. Both `keyup` and `keydown` events are fired for that key, but not a `keypress` event. Chrome also fires events similarly (no `keypress`).  The `keyCode` is the same on both Chrome and Firefox, but what they consider the key to be is different between the two. Chrome considers the key to be the "Meta" key, while Firefox considers it to be the  "OS" key. Thus, Firefox does not set the `metaKey` property to `true`, because from Firefox's point of view, the "Meta" key is not being pressed.

Firefox's current interpretation of the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key (and probably the Mac <kbd>Command</kbd>, but I have not tested) is contrary to the documentation at [KeyboardEvent.metaKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey). Either the Firefox code needs to change, or the documentation. At a minimum, the documentation should state the current situation. Without explanation of why this behavior is currently this way, I would consider it a bug in Firefox. Meanwhile, I have updated the [KeyboardEvent.metaKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey) page on MDN with a note that the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key does cause `metaKey` to be true (you may have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh the page).

In harmonizing the [documentation page for nsIDOMWindowUtils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMWindowUtils) with the source code ([nsIDOMWindowUtils](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/interfaces/base/nsIDOMWindowUtils.idl#279), [UIEvent.cpp](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/events/UIEvent.cpp)), I noticed in the source that additional modifier codes had been added, including `MODIFIER_OS` to indicate the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key separate from a "Meta" key.  I did not look into when exactly this change was made.

If you want to know that the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key was pressed when an event you are handling occurred, you will have to use handlers on both `keydown` and `keyup` that watch for and track the current state of the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key.

**Typical <kbd>Windows</kbd> events (`keydown` shown in full):**

The following was the console log after pressing and releasing the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key while monitoring `keydown`, `keypress` `input` and `keyup` events.

[image: Windows key <code>keydown</code> event]

**Firefox Typical events for <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>:**

[image: Firefox Typical events for Windows-z]

**Chrome Typical events for <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>:**

[image: Chrome Typical events for Windows-z]

**Using the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key as a modifier:**
As you can see in the above screenshots, you don't get a full sequence of events for <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> in either Firefox or Chrome. Compared to other key combos both are missing the `keydown` event for the <kbd>z</kbd>. Why that event was not fired is not clear to me. I suspect that it was swallowed by Windows.

Using the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key will be problematic. Windows will react to many key combinations including ones that are just slight mis-keyings performed by a user that is not being quite as careful as required. You are probably better off using a different modifier key, or combination of modifier keys that does not include the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key.

Another example: <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> results in a full sequence of 3 `keydown` events, a `keypress` event, and 3 `keyup` events in Firefox, whereas in Chrome the sequence does not fire the `keypress` event.

**Keyboard Shortcuts in general:**
The key combinations that are already assigned to different tasks vary from OS to OS, browser to browser, and user to user.  In general, if you are wanting to use a keyboard shortcut in an add-on which you are generally releasing, the best course of action is to have default keyboard shortcuts, but allow the user the option to define what shortcut to use for each action, or even if there is a shortcut for the action. The reality is that users will run into conflicts with other applications and browser extensions. Depending on what type of extension you are writing, changing keyboard shortcuts may, or may not, be possible at this time.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, but not as easily and it's presumably about to change (but this answer is future-proof).

Until [Firefox bug 1266437](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1266437) (for Windows) and [Firefox bug 1232918](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1232918) (for Linux) are resolved, you can't use `event.metaKey` or `event.getModifierstate("Meta")` to recognize the Windows key (aka Super or OS), but you can use `event.getModifierState("OS")`.

For the broadest compatibility, I'm implementing it like this:

```js
if (event.metaKey || event.getModifierState("OS")
|| event.getModifierState("Super") || event.getModifierState("Win") {
  // do stuff
}
```

I'm not sure any browser currently implements `Super`. `Win` is the value used by Internet Explorer, as noted on the Mozilla Developer Network's docs for [KeyboardEvent.getModifierState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/getModifierState). That page also lists `OS` as deprecated, but the replacement (`Meta`) won't work until bugs 1266437 and 1232918 are resolved.

In any event, there are no warnings or errors for naming nonexistent modifiers in this function.

That said, I strongly suggest against using <kbd>Meta</kbd> since it's supposed to be reserved (at least on Windows and Linux) for user-defined shortcuts. My own code is looking for modifiers to *prevent* website functions when they're pressed (my `// do stuff` is `return;`).

Comment: seems both the Windows and the Linux bugs are finally fixed! https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1232918#c13

Answer (score 1):

Short answer No,

Notice that the meta key on windows is nothing but the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> windows key.

As the time of this writing, Firefox 55 is released but it still can't detect the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> button been pressed by returning `false` in the `metaKey` property.
Because of a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1266437).

I think you're better off using <kbd>shiftKey</kbd> which has a property with the same name on the event object.